# C# Recursion Error - Extension Methods

Tags: c#, loops, methods, infinite

I get an error here saying that the program could not exit the infinite loop.

```
public static class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object obj = new Object();
        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetClassName());
    }

    public static string GetClassName(this object value)
    {
        return value.GetClassName();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your `GetClassName` calls with `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` which also calls `value.GetClassName` until... forever

Comment: Well yes - what method did you expect `value.GetClassName()` to call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*you need to change your extension method to say:*

```
return obj.GetType().Name;
```

your extension method is calling itself which is causing the infinite loop/recursion problem.